# chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab - entire page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension that captures web pages through a screenshot. What I would ideally like to do is screenshot the entire page - not just the window. I'm currently using Chromes built in  `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab` but this only captures the screen.

Is there a way to capture the entire document without having to take multiple screenshots of the window until I cover the entire document?

THanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't seen any extensions which do it without multiple screenshots + scroll.

Comment: You can use chrome.debugger to make a [full page screenshot](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot), but its height and width are limited to 16384.